# How to POST query to form handler file?

Tags: post, https, coldfusion

This is a bit unorthodox of an approach, but I need to post query values into a form handler. What I'm doing  is taking a query from a separate database and I need to post those query values into the action page that processes form values to submit to a different database table.

In this case, I don't have a form; I just need to post the values of the query into the form action page which will post those values and additional generated values to a dozen different tables. The reason I'm trying to do it this way because the form handler page that processes the form values has over 2,700 lines of code that takes those values and operates on them, running numerous `IF ELSE` operations to decide which table those values should go in based on other values; so simply querying the tables and directly inserting them is not an option.

How can I get the query values into form handler page without using a form?

Comment: 1. if your file (if I understood that right) has 2700 lines, then something is wrong. 2. a form post is nothing special, it is a simple http post. There are various options how to perform such a post, depending on your environment. If you are trying to post from php, then take a look at phps `cURL` extension. 3. again, if I understood that correct, then you want to include those posted values again into some form to post them again. Sure that is possible. you just have to pick the posted values as received when you create and fill the form and fill them into the input elements of the form.

Comment: Yes, its 2,700 lines (which I did not write). The form handler file takes the form values, operates on them to decide what kind of order it is and legal types that apply, then based on the results of the if else operations, it runs 30 different queries for where to put the form values. What I need is to put the values into the form handler without a form so the form handler can operate on the values and put them into the DB tables.

Comment: Which I answered to, as far as I can say.

Comment: The update to Dan's post gives a CF-specific answer, but as @arkascha said you just need something capable of generating a POST (such as cfhttp, cURL, etcetera).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can post to a page without using a form with the [`<cfhttp>`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html) tag.  You can use the [`<cfhttpparam>`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttpparam.html) tag to attach your query values.  If your query returns more than one row, you will have to use a loop, and possibly separate threads.

Example of using `<cfhttp>` to perform a `POST` (taken form the docs linked-to above):

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin" method="post" result="result" charset="utf-8"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="accountType" value="HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="Email" value="<gmail id>"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="Passwd" value="<password>"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="service" value="youtube"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="source" value="youtubecode"> 
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: I just have one other question on posting the cfhttpparam value to the other cfm page. Do I need to do anything special on either side to post the `cfhttpparam` to a `cfparam` on the page receiving the post? When I tried to pass the values, the `cfhttp` runs without returning any visible errors and I didn't see anything in the logs. However, the values aren't submitted to the DB when I check the DB table.